# Where is the question about the "uses of Dropbox"?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I vaguely recall a question – probably on Super User – about uses of Dropbox.

It was very popular and probably got deleted because of subjectivity. Does anybody have a link to an archive of it?

Comment: This? http://superuser.com/questions/4143/what-interesting-types-of-things-can-dropbox-be-used-for

Comment: ^For those with less reputation: ["what interesting types of things can dropbox be used for"](http://web.archive.org/web/20101104112721/http://superuser.com/questions/4143/what-interesting-types-of-things-can-dropbox-be-used-for)

Comment: thanks, I don't have the rep for the first one, and re the second one,  @iglvzx is there a way to view it with comments?

Comment: @barlop You mean "show X more comments" ? Not using `archive.org`.

Comment: I haven't used stackprinter much but howcome I can't find it on stackprinter? (like, entering the id 4143 doesn't come up with it)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/GRmP6a0g

Comment: @Nifle fantastic, many thanks

Comment: Perhaps someone should write a blog post about it if that person is so inclined to keep it. If only we had a blog to put it on...

Comment: @IvoFlipse i'm inefficient, it might be a few years before I get round to trying the uses(which I hope i'll find useful)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I put the content of the deleted question up on http://pastebin.com/GRmP6a0g